# Sharing data between svn hooks

Tags: svn, environment-variables, visualsvn-server, svn-hooks

Ive been using the pre-commit hook to run my executable and been trying to pass a string argument to be listed in the log of the revision i just committed.

after doing some digging, ive found that the best practice for changing the log message is using the post-commit hook to change the log message, the problematic part for me is to share the string from the .exe onto the post-commit hook.

things ive tried (maybe someone can shed a light on pros\cons):

1. Using Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(envname,value) and using %envname% inside the post-commit-hook.bat, that seems to be not working since the envname is being created with setX and assigned to machine rather than the user setting it from the exe process
2. Writing to the exe app.settings the values i want to preserve and re-call the .exe from the post-commit-hook

The 2nd try seems like its gonna work, but i think its a bit odd how theres no faster\intuitive solution for this

Any suggestion in that matter?